# mysql join mutliple children and one if only one exists

Tags: mysql

I have the following Situation:

```
t1
------
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
------


t2
----------------------
| id | pid | current |
|----|-----|----------
| 1  |  1  | 1       |
| 2  |  1  | NULL    |
| 3  |  2  | NULL    |
| 4  |  3  | 1       |
| 5  |  4  | NULL    |
| 6  |  4  | 1       |
----------------------
```

Expected Result:

```
---------
| t1.id |
|-------|
| 1     |
| 2     |
---------
```

In Words:
I want to select every t1, which has ( only one child with current IS NULL ) or ( at least 2 children, where there is at least one child with current IS NULL and a higher id than the one with current NOT NULL )

all the best

Comment: `= 0` is different from `IS NULL`. You don't have `0` values in your sample data, is that right?

Comment: Is there any reason behind this, or do you just want to make us think? A real life example and real life data usually make it more clear.

Comment: only one child with current = 0 ?? there is no current with 0 how he get those data in expected result ?

Comment: modify your example data. Table `t2` doesn't have any record having `current` as 0

Comment: oh sorry i meant current IS NULL not = 0

Comment: but pid = 4 is also NULL so why he is not in the expected result ?

Comment: if someone understand this `( at least 2 children, where there is at least one child with current IS NULL and a higher id than the one with current NOT NULL )` please tell what he mean , i dont understand anything